# Importing 3D DXF and using LRS

Tags: qgis, linear-referencing, dxf

I've got a dxf in AutoCAD with a different Z value in each vertex. I'm importing this dxf to QGIS and running the LRS plugin to work with some chainages.

My problem is that when running the chainage I'm not getting the same than my peers are getting in ArcGIS, by as much as 15m.

I think the issue could be that LRS is not reading the 3D elevations and treating the line as a 2D. Although if this was the case, the difference should be quite highers, since it's a 450km and there is more than 300m of difference between elevations at start and end.

Anyways, how do I make sure that the LRS plugin is taking in consideration the Z value?

Comment: That amount of variation could be caused by using a slightly different CRS and/or datum. Are you using the same CRS as your peers?

Comment: That's what I thought too. But that is not. Could it be the way ArcGIS do the math vs how qGIS does it?

Comment: The documentation for the LRS plugin doesn't mention using elevation or Z values in the calculation. I suspect the Z values are just being ignored.